# How do I apply more than one weapon enchantment in The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Is it possible to give a weapon in TES IV more than one enchantment? If so, how do I do it, and what are your personal recommendations for weapon/enchantment combinations for a warrior type character, destinated to apply maximum damage (balanced to hurt magical creatures like ghosts as much as non magical creatures like humans)?

Comment: Your initial question is a good one, but the second part of your question, asking for recommendations, isn't a good fit for the site: it might be better to ask for a specific purpose. Why do you want to combine enchantments: damage? sneak? boost attributes?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can find (and eventually enchant!) weapons with multiple enchantments, weapons in Oblivion only have two states: enchanted, and unenchanted. Once enchanted, weapons cannot be un-enchanted, and there is no way to add/subtract abilities, charge size, or effect magnitude after the initial enchantment.

If you haven't already, I'd suggest you look into the [Enchanting guide](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Enchanting) at the unofficial elder scrolls wiki. The wiki also contains a list of "[Useful Enchantments](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Useful_Enchantments)" which sounds like it might be useful for your purposes.